# Make a change in two modules via Client Script/Custom Function in Zoho CRM

Tags: javascript, crm, zoho, zoho-deluge

I'm trying to when altering the date checkbox to today's date (`Outbound`) in the module named `Tickets`, the other module named `commissions` change the specific commission status to `"approved"`. I already try a deluge code, but I'm not sure if it is working, I'm completely new to programming (last than 2 months) and i'm the only programmer in my job, so everything comes to me and I don't have a Senior programmer to ask questions or something, and the content online about Zoho is rather scarce.

This code was supposed to change the check box commission status to approved when the date box outbound date is today.

```
Tickets_list = zoho.crm.searchRecords("Tickets","(Outbound:equals:zoho.currentdate)");
Commission = zoho.crm.searchRecords("Commissions","Commission_Status");
for each  Ticket in Tickets_list
{
    zoho.crm.searchRecords("Commissions","Commission_Status");
    Commission_Update_Map = Map();
    Commission_Update_Map.put("Commission_Status","Approved");
    Commission_Update_Response = zoho.crm.updateRecord("Commissions",Commission.getJSON("id"),Commission_Update_Map);
    info Commission_Update_Response;
}
return "";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for each  Ticket in Tickets_list
{
    /*create a lookup in commission module and whenever a ticket is created update the Commissoion module's Ticket lookup with Ticket ID*/
    
    /*get ticket id*/
    ticket_id = Ticket.getJSON("id");
    /*searching the commission module with the linked ticket ID and the Commission status */
    commission_search_map = Map();
    commission_search_map.put("Commission_Status");
    commission_search_map.put("Ticket", ticket_id);
    commission_res = zoho.crm.searchRecords("Commissions",commission_search_map);
    // update the records found with the values you want to update 
    Commission_Update_Map = Map();
    Commission_Update_Map.put("Commission_Status","Approved");
    Commission_Update_Response = zoho.crm.updateRecord("Commissions",commission_res.getJSON("id"),Commission_Update_Map);
    info Commission_Update_Response;
}
```

Comment: Please include more educational comments as opposed to just a code snippet, especially since OP is new to programming